# [tag]weex[/tag] Do weex support order property in flexbox layouts?

Tags: weex

Do weex support order property in flexbox layouts?
I have tried the example in my android project, but it doesn't work.
Here is the [link](http://dotwe.org/vue/11ca78e6ff10f10001eae45d8d146970).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this feature like order or z-index in not support. And will not be supported recently.

The only way is to change the data-source order.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work on native (works on web though).

You can also let them know of these issues: https://github.com/alibaba/weex/issues